# Passing an object reference between classes AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Making a map creation program. Field.as instantiates _player. Player.as addsChild _editorPanel to parent. EditorPanel.as instantiates a movieclip called tilepalette when I click a button in the editor panel. Tilepalette holds all of my tilesets that I want to be able to choose a tile from by clicking the tile that I want.

**Field.as:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.FrameLabel;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Field extends MovieClip{

        private var player:Player;
        private var sampleTile:Tile = new Tile();
        private var _tilePalette:TilePalette;
        private var _paletteArray:Array = [];

        public function Field() 
        {
            player = new Player();
            player.x = 0;
            player.y = 0;
            addChild(player);

            GetSampleTiles();
        }

        private function GetSampleTiles()
        {
            for (var i:int = 1; i <= sampleTile.totalFrames; i++)
            {
                var tileObj:Object = new Object();

                sampleTile.gotoAndStop(i);

                var graphicData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32,32);
                graphicData.draw(sampleTile);

                tileObj.Name = sampleTile.currentFrameLabel;
                tileObj.Graphic = graphicData;
                tileObj.Frame = sampleTile.currentFrame;

                Engine._tilesData.push(tileObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.as:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;


    public class Player extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var _inp:Input = new Input();
        private var _playerXindex:int = 0;
        private var _playerYindex:int = 0;
        private var _heldTile:Object;
        private var _editorPanel:EditorPanel;

        public function Player() 
        {
            addChild(_inp);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HandleKeys);

            _heldTile = new Object();
        }

        private function HandleKeys(e:Event)
        {
            _playerXindex = x/32;
            _playerYindex = y/32;

            if(_inp.keyUp)
            {
                y -= 32;
            }
            if(_inp.keyDown)
            {
                y += 32;
            }
            if(_inp.keyLeft)
            {
                x -= 32;
            }
            if(_inp.keyRight)
            {
                x += 32;
            }
            if(_inp.keySpace)
            {
                try{DrawATile(_heldTile);}
                catch(err:Error){trace("Bad or no graphic. Using this instead.");}
                finally{DrawATile(Engine._tilesData[0]);}
            }
            if(_inp.keyA)
            {
                trace(Engine.tileObjIndex[_playerYindex][_playerXindex].Name);
            }
            if(_inp.keyB)
            {
                BuildStarterIndex();
                SetHeldTile(Engine._tilesData[0]);
            }
        }

        private function DrawATile(tileToDraw:Object)
        {
            if (Engine.tileObjIndex[_playerYindex][_playerXindex].Name.indexOf("Placeholder") >= 0)
            {
                trace("set");
                var graphicData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32,32);
                graphicData.draw(tileToDraw.Graphic);

                Engine.tileObjIndex[_playerYindex][_playerXindex].Name = tileToDraw.Name;
                Engine.tileObjIndex[_playerYindex][_playerXindex].Graphic = tileToDraw.Graphic;

                var newTile:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tileToDraw.Graphic);
                newTile.x = x;
                newTile.y = y;
                parent.addChild(newTile);
            }
        }

        private function BuildStarterIndex()
        {
            _editorPanel = new EditorPanel();
            _editorPanel.x = 1;
            _editorPanel.y = 544;
            parent.addChild(_editorPanel);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Engine.tileObjIndex[i] = [];

                for (var u:int = 0; u < 20; u++)
                {
                    var tileObj:Object = new Object();

                    var graphicData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32,32);
                    graphicData.draw(Engine._tilesData[0].Graphic);

                    tileObj.Name = "Placeholder" + "["+i+"]"+"["+u+"]";
                    tileObj.Graphic = graphicData;
                    tileObj.Frame = 0;

                    Engine.tileObjIndex[i].push(tileObj);
                }
            }
        }

        private function SetHeldTile(tiletoset:Object)
        {
            _heldTile.Name = tiletoset.Name;
            _heldTile.Graphic = tiletoset.Graphic;
            _heldTile.Frame = tiletoset.Frame;

            _editorPanel.tileName.text = _heldTile.Name;
            _editorPanel.tileFrame.text = _heldTile.Frame;

            var heldTile:Bitmap = new Bitmap(_heldTile.Graphic);
            heldTile.x = 30;
            heldTile.y = 31;
            _editorPanel.addChild(heldTile);
        }
    }
}
```

**EditorPanel.as:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class EditorPanel extends MovieClip
    {
        public var _tilePalette:TilePalette;
        private var _pArray:Array = [];
        private var _mouseXi:int;
        private var _mouseYi:int;
        public var _tileGrabbed:Object;

        public function EditorPanel() 
        {
            btnpalette.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BuildPalette);
        }

        private function UpdateMouse(e:Event)
        {
            _mouseXi = Math.floor(_tilePalette.mouseX/32);
            _mouseYi = Math.floor(_tilePalette.mouseY/32);
        }

        private function BuildPalette(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            _tilePalette = new TilePalette();
            _tilePalette.x = mouseX;
            _tilePalette.y = mouseY-256;
            addChild(_tilePalette);
            var counter:int = 1;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                _pArray[i] = [];
                for(var u:int = 0; u < 8; u++)
                {
                    if(counter >= Engine._tilesData.length)
                    {
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(Engine._tilesData[counter].Graphic);
                    b.x = 32 * u;
                    b.y = 32 * i;
                    _tilePalette.addChild(b);

                    _pArray[i].push(Engine._tilesData[counter]);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            _tilePalette.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, UpdateMouse);
            _tilePalette.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GrabATile);
        }

        private function GrabATile(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            return _pArray[_mouseXi][_mouseYi];
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I do GrabATile, I don't know what to do with the returned Object reference. I want to use that Object in the Player function SetHeldTile.

Comment: Help me understand what is going on here, the player has the ability to grab a tile, correct?

Comment: Well, I was kinda planning on that in the future, but for now I just want to be able to click the tile that I want from the tilePalette.

Comment: When it's played, you move the player around with the arrow keys and lay down the tile graphics with the spacebar. I made it set a default _heldTile when you press b.

Comment: You didn't write that code correct? Cos the code already does what you ask in one place so it doesn't make sense for you to not know how to do it unless you didn't write that code in the first place.

Comment: I did write the code. I halfway understand. It returns the object reference (_pArray[_mouseXi][_mouseYi]) but where does it return it to? How do I make the SetHeldTile function use that object reference as its argument??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this will make it work, but I would suggest looking to refactor that code a bit.  Adding children that add things to their parents is not the best design... There is also round robin stuff going on there where the editor selects the tile, but then the player sets things like tileName back on the editor after it is told about the new tile.  This should occur in the editor where tile selection occurs etc.

That said, depending on your flow, here is how to make it work:

EditorPanel already has a property _tileGrabbed.  so in your GrabATile() method just set

```
_tileGrabbed = _pArray[_mouseXi][_mouseYi];
```

Then in your setHeldTile() method... simply say

```
_heldTile = _editorPanel._tileGrabbed.
```

Now, if you need GrabATile() to TRIGGER setHeldTile(), the best way to handle that would be with an event.

```
// in EditorPanel

private function GrabATile(e:MouseEvent){
    _tileGrabbed =  _pArray[_mouseXi][_mouseYi];
    dispatchEvent(new Event("tileChanged"));
}

// in Player

private function BuildStarterIndex(){
    _editorPanel = new EditorPanel();
    _editorPanel.addEventListener("tileChanged", setHeldTile);
    // ... rest of code
}

private function SetHeldTile(event:Event){
    _heldTile = _editorPanel._tileGrabbed;
    // ... rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I played with custom events for a while on this and couldn't get it to work. I'm a bit new to having so many classes, so I'm going through some growing pains. I've already started re writing it... for like the 4th time. Haha. Thanks again

Comment: I read and read and look at numerous exmples, but it still doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. I get that child classes should "change their own diapers" and that I should avoid circular dependencies and all that but when I go to write it, it seems like I can't help but design it badly. The animal examples make total sense to me, but they're extremely straight forward. When it comes to writing more abstract classes I feel lost.

Comment: <smile>  I get ya!  It takes a while before it becomes "second nature" to design code.  The best advice I can hand ya is first think about single responsibility... meaning a class should do / represent one thing and only that thing.  It help a lot to "think" the code before you write the code.  Write it down on paper and isolate all the different things that need to exist and all the different actions that need to happen... the start separating it all out into classes that do those things.  You should also look at SOLID, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: And as far as circular references... think about things like this:  Does a Player really need a "heldTile" property?  A tile has nothing to do with a player.  They are 2 separate unrelated "things". It would be far better design to create a model class with a "activeTile" property and whenever a player needs to know about it, or code looking to see if the player and tile are near each other for example, that code can just look at model.activeTile. Do some googling about MVC (model view controller) and how the responsibilities of classes are divided up! You'll get your "ah ha" moment... promise

Comment: I appreciate your encouragement. I feel like I just keep asking dumb questions. Haha. I think I'm starting to get it. These really helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293429/how-to-avoid-having-messy-as3-code and http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/698/4/Make-your-own-reusable-classes-using-Flash-and-AS3/Page1.html I wrote a class called HandleTiles that does all of the things that tiles need to do. I also wrote a class called HandleGraphics that currently only has one function (DrawGrid) that works great. Now, should HandleTile or HandleGraphics have the function DrawATile?

Comment: not sure about the exact content of your new classes, but from your description of them, HandleGraphics is doing simple drawing and HandleTiles is "handling" the tiles.  So sounds like HandleTiles would be the class to "create" and store a reference to the created tiles based on your new setup

Comment: Or should I break them down even further and call HandleGraphics something more specific, like HandleBasicGraphics... or HandleSprites. Also, I plan on being able to load different SpriteSheets or TileSets. I think they'll either be different MovieClips, or the same MovieClip and just define the sets by the frame numbers and labels (tediously keep track). Anywho, should I make more classes, like BuildingTiles and ItemTiles that extend HandleTiles?